# Is there any way to merge my two accounts point of SO into one?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

I have my main account that I have been using for quite some time from home. Recently I joined a new company and so I created a new SO account. I fear that if I use my main account the passwords might be discovered by my network admin because my main account uses Yahoo OpenID of SO. So I created a new account on Gmail which I don't use frequently, and used Google OpenID to create a new account on SO.  Now I have a few points on my 2nd account also. Can I merge both of them into one? So, no matter whichever login I use whether Yahoo or Gmail, they both should should show the net sum of the points of both accounts.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, link both accounts here (or at least the account that you did not post this from) so that a moderator can merge them.  Currently you can have up to 2 OpenIDs associated with one account.

Answer (score 2):

From "[How can one link/merge accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)"

> To merge multiple accounts within a specific site, or registered
>   accounts between two different websites, email is no longer the
>   preferred method of handling this, since the dev team has many other
>   things to do.
>
> First, there are [automated processes that merge accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste). Wait a
>   bit to see if things are resolved automatically.
>
> If not, follow this procedure:
>
> Set the email address of your registered account to the address used
>   in your other account. Since email is not visible to anyone, this will
>   confirm that you own both accounts.
>
> Some people have had trouble with this step. If you have two
>   registered accounts and cannot make the email addresses the same, an
>   alternative option is to make a note in one of the profiles: "Please
>   merge this account into ."
>
> Flag one of your posts for moderator attention and ask for a merge:

[image]

> If the details match, we will go ahead and merge with no further ado.
>   If we feel we need more confirmation for some reason, we will either
>   comment or email to tell you.

Comment: This would have been a good chance to try out that "possible duplicate" flag, eh?

Comment: @Cody I flagged it also.